# Require declaration of properties before assignment

Tags: php, properties, declaration, error-reporting

The following is legal in php.

```
class Foo{
    function setBar($bar){
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to generate a notice that property `Foo#bar` hasn't been declared before use? 
I'm sick of wasting time debugging typos.

Comment: use a good IDE that can generate getters and setters for you, all you need to do is declare the private properties. ZendStudio comes to mind

Comment: @Ibu this might be light offtopic, but are there any FREE/low-cost IDEs that can do this ?

Comment: @Panique yes, you can use Eclipse for php development, Zend is Based on Eclipse anyway

Comment: unless you want to pay fro Zend Studio, Eclipse won't do it out of the box. There's a plugin e-surf but their update site seems to be down at the moment. I created a code template (below) which helps Preference->PHP->Editor->Templates :
public function get${type}(){
 return $$this->${variable};
}
public function set${type}(${type} $$${variable}){
 $$this->${variable} = $$${variable};
}

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are after:

```
class Foo
{    
  function setBar( $bar )
  {
    $this->bar = $bar;
  }

  public function __set( $name, $value )
  {
    throw new Exception( 'Can not set property ' . $name );
  }    
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setBar( 'bar' );
```

What happens here is that when a class property is called that is out of scope, the magic __get or __set is called. There you can decide how to handle that situation.

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting approach although would require adding this code to every class/base class which I'd rather not do. You'd think php would issue an E_NOTICE.

Comment: It is up to you how to handle it. You can use a base class, and issue a E_NOTICE, if you wish

Comment: Point is I don't want to write code to check for correctness - I'd like either php or some type of lint program to do it. I guess this could go in a trait in php >=5.4 though which would keep it out of the way at least.